# Accessing Controller.Request from Class.cs

Tags: c#, .net, post, get

I moved a method from a `controller` to a `class.cs`. When I did, the `Request.Form` stopped working.

```
NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form; //Sent as post from client
```

Is there another way to do the same outside of a `Controller`?

Comment: better would be to pass the `Form` object as parameter to that method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need :

```
HttpContext.Current.Request
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I need :) Do you happen to know how to do the same for Controller.Json?

Comment: You can use  DataContractJsonSerializer if you have a datacontract with Datamember attributes cf : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx . But it is probably easier to just return your result and use the json method from the controller